# Android Chromium Browser gclient sync failure

Tags: android, python, centos, synchronization, chromium

I have successfully got the code using `fetch android`.Now while running the **gclient sync**, i received this error.How can i resolve this?
Thanks in advance.

```
    $ gclient sync
    Syncing projects: 100% (93/93), done.                                         

    ________ running '/usr/bin/python src/build/landmines.py' in '/home/s_sharma/chromium_browser'

    ________ running '/usr/bin/python src/build/download_nacl_toolchains.py --mode nacl_core_sdk sync --extract' in '/home/s_sharma/chromium_browser'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "src/build/download_nacl_toolchains.py", line 59, in <module>
        sys.exit(Main(sys.argv[1:]))
      File "src/build/download_nacl_toolchains.py", line 53, in Main
        package_version.main(args)
      File "/home/s_sharma/chromium_browser/src/native_client/build/package_version/package_version.py", line 1288, in main
        arguments = ParseArgs(args)
      File "/home/s_sharma/chromium_browser/src/native_client/build/package_version/package_version.py", line 1196, in ParseArgs
        verbose=arguments.verbose, quiet=arguments.quiet)
      File "/home/s_sharma/chromium_browser/src/native_client/pynacl/log_tools.py", line 94, in SetupLogging
        console_handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
    TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'stream'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/s_sharma/depot_tools/gclient.py", line 2300, in <module>
        sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
      File "/home/s_sharma/depot_tools/gclient.py", line 2286, in main
        return dispatcher.execute(OptionParser(), argv)
      File "/home/s_sharma/depot_tools/subcommand.py", line 245, in execute
        return command(parser, args[1:])
      File "/home/s_sharma/depot_tools/gclient.py", line 2043, in CMDsync
        ret = client.RunOnDeps('update', args)
      File "/home/s_sharma/depot_tools/gclient.py", line 1528, in RunOnDeps
        self.RunHooksRecursively(self._options)
      File "/home/s_sharma/depot_tools/gclient.py", line 983, in RunHooksRecursively
        hook, cwd=self.root.root_dir, always=True)
      File "/home/s_sharma/depot_tools/gclient_utils.py", line 293, in CheckCallAndFilterAndHeader
        return CheckCallAndFilter(args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/s_sharma/depot_tools/gclient_utils.py", line 538, in CheckCallAndFilter
        rv, args, kwargs.get('cwd', None), None, None)
      File "/home/s_sharma/depot_tools/subprocess2.py", line 37, in __init__
        super(CalledProcessError, self).__init__(returncode, cmd, output=stdout)
    TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'output'
    [s_sharma@localhost chromium_browser]$
```